# structural pattern matching: match a type object to a certain class

Tags: python, structural-pattern-matching

I would like to write a pattern matching block that detects whether the object being matched is the `type`/class object, for example, `int` or `str`. *Not an instance of these*, but the **actual class object** `int` or `str`.

This is a `SyntaxError`:

```
x = int

match x:
    case str:
        print("x is str")
    case int:
        print("x is int")
```

How to do it?

UPDATE, the following does NOT work, but the `SyntaxError` is at least solved:

```
x = int

match [x]:
    case [str]:
        print("x is str")
    case [int]:
        print("x is int")
```

(Incorrect result: `x is str`)

UPDATE: the problem is that the bare `int` or `str` is a [capture pattern](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=case#capture-patterns) and note a [value pattern](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=case#value-patterns). The name `int` or `str` would be BOUND with a naked `case int:` or `case str:`. You have to use something wit dot notation to make it not capture.

This works:

```
import builtins

x = int

match x:
    case builtins.str:
        print("x is str")
    case builtins.int:
        print("x is int")
```

For a non-builtin, you must do something like:

```
import mymodule

x = mymodule.MyClass

match x:
    case mymodule.MyClass:
        print("x is MyClass")
    case mymodule.MyOtherClass:
        print("x is MyOtherClass")
```